# A field or property with the name 'X' was not found on the selected data source

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist

This might be a long post but I've tried a lot to fix it and haven't figured it out.

I am creating an ASP GUI for a user to look up employee info. It has a dropdown list for what team they are on and then there are 18 checkbox lists that are being used as filters for what the user wants to search by. I have a data source that grabs 19 columns of employee information all from one table so there's no joins here.

[image]

My Problem:

It works fine when I just use the dropdown list for the user to select a team and no checkboxes are checked. It returns the all employees and their information from the team I chose along with all columns in the database. But when I check any box such as 'First Name' (which has the column name Fname in my database) I will get an error saying "A field or property with the name 'Lname' was not found on the selected data source." Lname is the next column in my table (with the alias name 'Last Name' in my GUI). If I run the GUI again and check the boxes 'first name" and 'last name', it will return the same error but instead of it saying 'Lname' was not found on the data source, it will say the next column which is UserID. If I check all the boxes it will return with the same error but with the column name 'Team' was not found. The column 'Team' is being used for the dropdown list.

Looking at the SQL Command at the bottom after the error happens, it shows a correct SQL statement of `"SELECT Fname, Lname FROM Info WHERE Team = 'DB2'"` and that's when I select the team DB2 from the dropdown list and select the checkboxes Fname and Lname.

Here is my cs code:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string SQLCmd = "SELECT *";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SQLQueryBuilder();
        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = SQLCmd;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    private void SQLQueryBuilder()
    {
        foreach (ListItem i in CheckBoxList1.Items)
        {
            if (i.Selected == true)
            {
                SQLCmd = SQLCmd.Remove(SQLCmd.Length - 1);
                SQLCmd += i.Value + ",  ";                                     
            }                                                                    
        }

        if (SQLCmd.EndsWith(",  "))
        {
            SQLCmd = SQLCmd.Remove(SQLCmd.Length - 3);
        }

        SQLFromClause();

        if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue != "Please Select a Team...")
        {
            SQLWhereClause();
            SQLCmd += " Team = '" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "'";
        }                        
    }

    private void SQLFromClause()
    {
        SQLCmd += " FROM Info";
    }

    private void SQLWhereClause()
    {
        SQLCmd += " WHERE";            
    }
}
}
```

I've tried modifying my SQL Statement here and there but it is returning the correct column names and correct SQL Statement so I don't think it's that.

Here is my source code for the GUI:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/PhoneList.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="PhoneList.WebForm1" %>
```

```
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" Height="16px" RepeatColumns="3" style="position:absolute; top: 118px; left: 7px; z-index: 1; height: 152px; width: 350px;">
        <asp:ListItem Value="Fname" Selected="True">First Name</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Lname" Selected="True">Last Name</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="UserID" Selected="True">User ID</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Deskphone" Selected="True">Desk Phone</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Cellphone" Selected="True">Cell Phone</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Home" Selected="True">Home Phone</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Workhours" Selected="True">Work Hours</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="RDO" Selected="True">RDO</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Telework" Selected="True">Telework</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Laptopnum" Selected="True">Laptop #</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Desktopnum" Selected="True">Desktop #</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Monitor1" Selected="True">Monitor 1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Monitor2" Selected="True">Monitor 2</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="USB" Selected="True">USB</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="WorkspaceID" Selected="True">Workspace ID</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Birthday" Selected="True">Birthday</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="IP" Selected="True">IP Address</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Laptopmodel" Selected="True">Laptop Model</asp:ListItem>
     </asp:CheckBoxList>

    <asp:Label ID="lblFilter" runat="server" Text="Filters:" style="position:absolute; top: 96px; left: 14px;"></asp:Label>

    <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" Text="Search" style="position:absolute; top: 274px; left: 13px;" />

    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" style="position:absolute; margin-top: 0px; top: 70px; left: 11px;">
        <asp:ListItem>Please Select a Team...</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>DB2</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Oracle</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>SQL</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Sybase</asp:ListItem>        
    </asp:DropDownList>

</p>
<p>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" style="left: 7px;">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC99" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Fname" HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="Fname" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Lname" HeaderText="Last Name" SortExpression="Lname" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="UserID" HeaderText="User ID" SortExpression="UserID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Deskphone" HeaderText="Desk Phone" SortExpression="Deskphone" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Cellphone" HeaderText="Cell Phone" SortExpression="Cellphone" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Home" HeaderText="Home Phone" SortExpression="Home" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Workhours" HeaderText="Work Hours" SortExpression="Workhours" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="RDO" HeaderText="RDO" SortExpression="RDO" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Telework" HeaderText="Telework" SortExpression="Telework" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Laptopnum" HeaderText="Laptop #" SortExpression="Laptopnum" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Desktopnum" HeaderText="Desktop #" SortExpression="Desktopnum" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Monitor1" HeaderText="Monitor 1" SortExpression="Monitor1" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Monitor2" HeaderText="Monitor 2" SortExpression="Monitor2" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="USB" HeaderText="USB" SortExpression="USB" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="WorkspaceID" HeaderText="Workspace ID" SortExpression="WorkspaceID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Birthday" HeaderText="Birthday" SortExpression="Birthday" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="IP" HeaderText="IP Address" SortExpression="IP" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Laptopmodel" HeaderText="Laptop Model" SortExpression="Laptopmodel" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Team" HeaderText="Team" SortExpression="Team" />
        </Columns>
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#FF9900" />
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ExampleConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT Fname, Lname, UserID, Deskphone, Cellphone, Home, Workhours, RDO, Telework, Laptopnum, Desktopnum, Monitor1, Monitor2, USB, WorkspaceID, Birthday, IP, Laptopmodel, Team FROM Info"> 
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
</p>
<p>

    &nbsp;</p>
<p>
    &nbsp;</p>
```

I've tried having the select command be `SELECT * FROM Info` originally but that didn't change anything. All of the column names are clearly correct since when I only use the dropdown list without clicking any checkboxes, it returns the correct data. When I copy the SQL Command that the script generates and paste it directly into my SQL Server Management Studio, it brings back the correct information so I don't know what the problem is!

Comment: Interesting way of building a query... But if you select only 2 columns, but still bind the data to the GridView you will get that error because you specify all the columns as BoundField.

Comment: Yeah I'm kind of new to C#. It worked so I just kind of left it. lol What should I change it to? TemplateField then orr.....?

Comment: If you bind data to the GridView with variable columns I suggest setting `AutoGenerateColumns` to true.

Comment: What do you mean by variable columns? I checked the box while the columns are still BoundField called `AutoGenerateColumns` and it created each column twice so pretty much two tables are side by side combined into one table and when I chose a team and used 2 checkbox columns I still got the same error.

Comment: `SELECT Fname, Lname` or `SELECT Fname, Lname, UserID` are datasets with variable columns. 2 vs 3 columns.

Comment: Changing it to autogeneratedcolumns worked but is there a way to edit the formatting of these columns such as having some of columns' data to be centered and some to be left aligned?

Comment: With AutoGenerateColumns you can only do that in the RowDataBound event. You can also make sure all the columns are in the dataset, even if they are dummies and then you could use BoundField: `SELECT Fname, Lname, NULL as UserID, NULL as Deskphone etc.. FROM Info WHERE Team = 'DB2'`

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because you try to bind all the columns in GridView1 where you show the result. When you uncheck one field, you remove it from your query, so it is not part of the resultset. However, you still try to bind a column to it:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Fname" HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="Fname" />
```

Comment: What should I change it to? TemplateField?

Comment: As @VDWWD said, set `AutoGenerateColumns` to true on the gridview, and remove all the boundfields

Comment: wow. That worked. I messed with that setting before but I never removed the boundfields at all.

Comment: But is there a way to edit the formatting of these columns such as having some of columns' data to be centered and some to be left aligned?

Comment: sure, but you should post that in a different question